# Python in Selnuim - How to access the contents of Shadowroot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcQHs.png)

I'm trying to get full content under shadow-root and print so that I know whether I am selecting the right nodes later in the code. The issue is that I'm unable to extract the contents of shadow-root.

I'm trying to click on button called process is final goal. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
 shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments [0]'); 
 shadowRoot', element)
 return shadow_root
shadow_section = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*     - 
[@id='shellNavComponent']")
time.sleep(1)
shadow_section=expand_shadow_element(shadow_section)
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', 
shadow_section)
time.sleep(1)

element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul:nth-child(2)')
text_content = driver.execute_script('return arguments [0]'); 
textContent', element)
```

Print the HTML content

```
print(text_content)
```

Comment: When you post a question, please take a minute to look at the preview of the question to make sure the code, etc. is properly formatted. I fixed as much as I could but you're going to have to fix the indent of your code to whatever you are using.

Comment: Also, screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: Thanks  for making me  knowledgeable.

Comment: You still need to fix the code indent.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is an iframe with its contents in it. The contents of the iframe can be easily accessed using jquery
Try use

```
$("iframe").contents()
```

You will receive the contents
Try returning this value to webdriver

```
return $("iframe").contents()
```

In case you don't want to use jquery
Try using
js

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]
```

Also, return this value

```
return document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
```

It does not return the entire html but you can control it and return a specific value using

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#player")
```

you can try it on console in any WebBrowser

Comment: This question is about python, not jquery.

Comment: @JeffC My friend Selenium in Python does browser control
your
He is now in his question wants to control the iframe
It returns and iframe source code
Selnuim can return js or jquery
From the browser to Python
by using driver.execute_script("JS CoDE")

Comment: by using $("iframe").contents(); We can control the iframe and when using
"return" Selenium return data from browser to python

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use jquery to switch frames when it's natively available in python.

Comment: Selenium cannot be used to return an iframe value easy by using python only. Normally, the best solution to return an iframe value is by using js,
If you have a solution please write it instead of objecting to a solution to our friend

Comment: First off, this question has nothing to do with IFRAMEs. It has to do with shadow-root. Secondly, python can easily switch IFRAMEs using `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)`. Not sure how you can get any easier than that... way easier than using JS inside python.